# SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, ssl, simple-salesforce, network, sslexception

Following details I gave and try to connect salesforce via simple_salesforce,

```
Salesforce(instance_url = 'https://********.my.salesforce.com',
        username = 'asdasd@asd.com',
        password = 'password',
            security_token = '******hhhh*******',
        domain = 'test')
```

Following Exception is coming when I connect with office network.

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.salesforce.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/Soap/u/52.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

If I disconnect with Office network and connect with other network(like mobile's hotspot) means, Its working fine. I don't know where is issue? In network or python?

Answer (score 1):

This is a network issue.

Your company either has:

- A proxy that is terminating TLS so that they can see the content of HTTPS requests entering and leaving the company network
- Installed a root certificate (self-signed) on your machine, which has the same effect (they can see HTTPS traffic)

This is a common (I think) network security practice for companies. You'll need to work with your IT and/or Network Security team to get through this issue. Provide the error you're getting to them, and they ought to know what they need to do to fix their network issue.